# My sql query with two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables named person and person_sibling. The `person_sibling` table contains the sibling id which refer to the sibling of the person( For ex: sibling of the person `SANGEETHA` is `SURESH`). I need to get all the names whose age is older than their sibling  age. The table data is shown below

`Person` table:

```
NAME       AGE   FNAME         ID   GENDER

SANGEETHA   20  PONNURANGAM     2   FEMALE
SARANYA     22  CHOKALINGAM     3   FEMALE
KANNA       22  ALAGRI          4   MALE
LAVANYA     21  MUNISWAMI       1   FEMALE
SURESH      25  PONNURANGAM     20  MALE
SARALA      26  CHOKALINGAM     21  FEMALE
KARAN       20  ALAGRI          2   MALE
ARTHI       20  ALAGRI          25  FEMALE
```

`person_sibling` table:

```
ID  SIBLING_ID

2   20
3   21
4   25
4   22
20  2
21  3
25  4
22  4
22  25
25  22
```

I've tried this:

```
SELECT name
FROM person p , person_sibling s
where p.id=s.sibling_id and p.age <=(select age from person where id=s.sibling_id)
```

But I can't able to get it. Can someone help please

Comment: can you show us what is the expected output of your query?

Comment: Just to make it clear, do you want to find all people that have a younger sibling (no matter if they also have an older one) or people that are the oldest sibling (that is, they have no older sibling)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.name
FROM person p
inner join person_sibling s on p.id = s.id
inner join person sp on s.sibling_id = sp.id
where p.age > sp.age
```

Answer (score 1):

A left join can give you all people that don't have an older sibling, it'll join to find all older siblings and a null check will just give you the rows where none exists.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM person p
LEFT JOIN person_sibling ps ON p.id = ps.id
LEFT JOIN person s ON ps.sibling_id = s.id AND s.age > p.age
WHERE s.id IS NULL;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6634b/7).